SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' from node_modules
I want to use browser-image-hash npm package in a project.
For setting up the project I did:

npm init -y
npx tsc --init
npm install browser-image-hash

I then added an index.ts file with the following code:
import { Hash } from "browser-image-hash";

const srcHash = new Hash(
  "0111011001110000011110010101101100110011000100110101101000111000"
).toString();


console.log(srcHash);

I added a few scripts to package.json, making it the following:
{
  "name": "image_matching_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-image-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

Upon doing npm run dev I got the following error:
    export { default as DifferenceHashBuilder } from './DifferenceHashBuilder';
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Following is my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

After I got this error I added a "type": "module" field in package.json, but I still got the following error:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

I also changed the module key in tsconfig.json to es2015 instead of commonjs, but then the module itself became irr-recognisable:
Cannot find module 'browser-image-hash'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

1 import { Hash } from "browser-image-hash";

Setting it to es6 also gave the same error. Setting it to nodenext also didn't help.
What am I missing here?
